# mock problem

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

//IsExist always false,is it a bug?

```
  [TestMethod]
   public void IsExist()
   {
       private Mock<IRepository> repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
                   Foo f = new Foo();
                   repository.Expect(s => s.IsExist(foo)).Returns(true);
       var controller = new MyController(repository.Object);
       var result = (ViewResult)controller.DoSometing();

   }

           public class MyController : Controller
           {

           IRepository _repository ;

           public MyController(IRepository repository)
   {
       _repository = repository;

   }

           public ViewResult DoSometing()
   {
       bool IsExist = _repository.IsExist(new Foo());
                   //IsExist always false,is it a bug?
       return View(foo);
   }

           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, which mocking library are you using (the answer may change based on that)?

I know if you were using Rhino Mocks, the problem would be that your expectation is set up to return true when it receives that specific instance of `foo` that you create at the top. This is a different instance to what is being passed in when its executed in your controller, so it returns false (since no expectation was set against *that* version of the `foo` object). To be clearer, if you had this code:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = new Foo();
repository.Expect(s => s.IsExist(f1)).Returns(true);
bool b1 = repository.Object.IsExist(f1);
bool b2 = repository.Object.IsExist(f2);
```

I would expect that `b1` would be true (since that's the specific expectation you set up, i.e. given `f1` return `true`) and `b2` would be false (since you didn't tell the repository to do anything specific if it received `f2`, so it will fall back to its default behaviour of returning false).

In Rhino Mocks, you'd need to set up your expectation like this:

```
repository.Expect(s => s.IsExist(Arg<Foo>.Is.TypeOf)).Returns(true);
```

which would return true if IsExist was called with *any* instance of a Foo object. If you needed to be more specific, you could have something like this:

```
repository.Expect(s => s.IsExist(f => f.SomeProperty == "blah" && f.OtherProperty.StartsWith("baz")))).Returns(true);
```

which would return true if `foo.SomeProperty` equaled `"blah"` and `foo.OtherProperty` started with `"baz"`.

Doesn't look like you're using Rhino Mocks, as your syntax is a little different, but hopefully that points you in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your object properties with some values before checking if it exists.

```
 public ViewResult DoSometing()
   {
       Foo obj = new Foo();
       obj.Property1 = "some value";
       bool IsExist = _repository.IsExist(obj);
                   //IsExist always false,is it a bug?
       return View(foo);
   }
```